# Определение округлённого числа

Tags: html, javascript

Есть код Javascript:

> `num = document.getElementById('input').value`
>
> `result = Number((num).toFixed(2))`

Если, допустим, input value="4+3+4", то среднее арифметическое result=3.66. Как сделать так, если значение result равно 3 целых и сколько-то десятых, то оно станет оранжевого цвета #FF6600, а если 4 или 5 целых и сколько-то десятых, то число станет зелёного цвета #299900?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(result < 4) {
    //color #FF6600
}
else {
    //color #299900 
}
```